Optimizing Search Speed for Vector Similarity in a Filtered Collection Schema
My collection schema is as follows:
fields = [
    FieldSchema(name="id", dtype=DataType.INT64, is_primary=True),
    FieldSchema(name="text", dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=512),
    FieldSchema(name="word", dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=512),
    FieldSchema(name="tag", dtype=DataType.VARCHAR, max_length=16),
    FieldSchema(name="vector", dtype=DataType.FLOAT_VECTOR, dim=768)
]

schema = CollectionSchema(fields)

I want to filter by word == "apple" and calculate the vector similarity among the filtered data to retrieve the tag values of the top 10 most similar data points. How can I optimize the search speed for this task?
Thanks.

You can specify partition_key_field to "apple" when you create the collection schema, so that Milvus distributes incoming entities into different partitions according to their respective partition values in this field. More detailed information can be found here on Milvus documentation: https://milvus.io/docs/use-partition-key.md#Use-Partition-Key
